How to connect Brother DCP 9022 CDW to Debian Testing
I use a Debian Testing system that is about a month old. In the office there is a Brother DCP 9022 CDW available over network.
Using a Kubuntu 24.04 live stick the printer is available without any further actions. As soon as I am attached to the LAN, the printer is detected and I was able to print a test page. I did not even have to add it myself.
I suspected the difference might be a missing package. Thus, I compared the list of installed packages reported by apt list --installed for Kubuntu Live and Debian Testing. Unfortunately, it did not help. In case I missed something, I include the list of packages which are available on Kubuntu only:
alsa-base
amd64-microcode
appmenu-gtk3-module
appmenu-gtk-module-common
apport
apport-core-dump-handler
apport-kde
apport-symptoms
bluez-cups
bpfcc-tools
bpftrace
busybox-initramfs
busybox-static
calamares
calamares-settings-kubuntu
calamares-settings-ubuntu-common
casper
cifs-utils
clinfo
command-not-found
cpp-13
cpp-13-x86-64-linux-gnu
cracklib-runtime
cups-bsd
dbus-x11
desktop-file-utils
dhcpcd-base
distro-info
dmeventd
dmraid
dolphin-plugins
dracut-install
e2fsprogs-l10n
ed
elisa
enchant-2
ethtool
fcitx5
fcitx5-chinese-addons
fcitx5-chinese-addons-bin
fcitx5-chinese-addons-data
fcitx5-config-qt
fcitx5-data
fcitx5-frontend-all
fcitx5-frontend-gtk3
fcitx5-frontend-gtk4
fcitx5-frontend-qt5
fcitx5-frontend-qt6
fcitx5-material-color
fcitx5-module-chttrans
fcitx5-module-cloudpinyin
fcitx5-module-fullwidth
fcitx5-module-lua
fcitx5-module-lua-common
fcitx5-module-pinyinhelper
fcitx5-module-punctuation
fcitx5-modules
fcitx5-pinyin
fcitx5-pinyin-gui
fcitx5-table
ffmpeg
finalrd
firmware-sof-signed
fonts-ibm-plex
fonts-katex
fonts-noto-hinted
fonts-ubuntu
freerdp2-x11
friendly-recovery
ftp
fwupd-signed
gcc-13-base
gdb
genisoimage
gir1.2-udisks-2.0
gnupg-agent
go-mtpfs
grub-gfxpayload-lists
grub-pc
grub-pc-bin
grub-theme-breeze
gstreamer1.0-pipewire
haruna
hdparm
hplip
hplip-data
humanity-icon-theme
hyphen-en-ca
hyphen-fi
hyphen-ga
hyphen-id
ibverbs-providers
ieee-data
im-config
info
initramfs-tools-bin
inputattach
iputils-tracepath
jfsutils
kaccounts-integration
kcharselect
kde-config-fcitx5
kde-config-gtk-style-preview
kde-config-plymouth
kde-config-tablet
kde-config-whoopsie
kdegames-card-data-kf5
kdegames-mahjongg-data-kf5
kdenetwork-filesharing
kerneloops
keyboxd
keyutils
kio-admin
kio-audiocd
kio-fuse
kio-gdrive
kmahjongg
kmines
konversation
konversation-data
kpartx
kpartx-boot
kpat
krdc
ksudoku
ksystemlog
kubuntu-desktop
kubuntu-installer-prompt
kubuntu-notification-helper
kubuntu-settings-desktop
kubuntu-wallpapers
kubuntu-web-shortcuts
kuserfeedback-doc
kwin-addons
kwin-decoration-oxygen
lame
language-pack-en
language-pack-en-base
language-selector-common
libabsl20220623t64
libaio1t64
libappindicator3-1
libappmenu-gtk3-parser0
libatm1t64
libavcodec60
libavdevice60
libavfilter9
libavformat60
libavutil58
libbabeltrace1
libbpfcc
libburn4t64
libc6-dbg
libcanberra0t64
libc-devtools
libcdio-cdda2t64
libcdio-paranoia2t64
libchm1
libclang1-18
libclang-cpp18
libcmark0.30.2
libcrack2
libcupsfilters2-common
libcupsfilters2t64
libdbus-glib-1-2
libdevmapper-event1.02.1
libdmraid1.0.0.rc16
libenchant-2-2
libestr0
libfastjson4
libfcitx5config6
libfcitx5core7
libfcitx5gclient2
libfcitx5-qt1
libfcitx5-qt6-1
libfcitx5-qt-data
libfcitx5utils2
libfreecell-solver0
libfreerdp2-2t64
libfreerdp-client2-2t64
libgl1-amber-dri
libgnustep-base1.29
libgpg-error-l10n
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
libheif-plugin-aomdec
libibverbs1
libicu74
libime-bin
libimecore0
libime-data
libime-data-language-model
libimepinyin0
libimetable0
libimobiledevice6
libinih1
libisoburn1t64
libisofs6t64
libjpeg8
libjpeg-turbo8
libjs-katex
libjxl0.7
libkcolorpicker0
libkf5baloowidgets-data
libkf5cddb5
libkf5compactdisc5
libkf5guiaddons-bin
libkf5js5t64
libkf5kdegames7
libkf5kdegames-data
libkf5kdelibs4support5
libkf5kmahjongglib5
libkf5pulseaudioqt3
libkf5sane5
libkf5sane-data
libkf5sysguard-bin
libkimageannotator0
libkpim5gapicore5
libkpim5gapi-data
libkpim5gapidrive5
libksanecore1
libksignalplotter9
libkubuntu1
libldap2
liblept5
libllvm18
liblsofui9
liblua5.3-0
liblvm2cmd2.03
libmarisa0
libmng2
libmpv2
libmujs3
libmusicbrainz5cc2v5
libneon27t64-gnutls
libnetplan1
libnotify-bin
libolm3
libolm-dev
libopencc1.1
libopencc-data
libpam-cap
libpcre3
libplacebo338
libpoppler134
libpoppler-cpp0t64
libpostproc57
libppd2
libppd2-common
libpwquality1
libpwquality-common
libqalculate22t64
libqapt3
libqapt3-runtime
libqt5hunspellinputmethod5
libqt5location5
libqt5location5-plugins
libqt5positioning5-plugins
libqt5positioningquick5
libqt5serialport5
libqt5xmlpatterns5
libqt6dbus6t64
libqt6gui6t64
libqt6network6t64
libqt6opengl6t64
libqt6waylandeglclienthwintegration6
libqt6waylandeglcompositorhwintegration6
libqt6widgets6t64
libquotient0.7
librav1e0
libre2-10
libroc0.3
libsane-hpaio
libsignon-extension1
libsixel1
libsnapd-glib-2-1
libsnapd-qt-2-1
libsource-highlight4t64
libsource-highlight-common
libssh-gcrypt-4
libsvtav1enc1d1
libswresample4
libswscale7
libtaskmanager6
libtesseract5
libtraceevent1
libtraceevent1-plugin
libtracefs1
libunibreak5
libuniconf4.6t64
libusbmuxd6
libvncclient1
libwhoopsie0
libwhoopsie-preferences0
libwinpr2-2t64
libwireplumber-0.4-0
libwvstreams4.6t64-base
libwvstreams4.6t64-extras
libx265-199
libxcb-ewmh2
libxcb-imdkit1
libxpresent1
libyaml-cpp0.8
linux-firmware
linux-generic
linux-headers-6.8.0-31
linux-headers-6.8.0-31-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-6.8.0-31-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-modules-6.8.0-31-generic
linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-31-generic
linux-sound-base
linux-tools-6.8.0-31
linux-tools-6.8.0-31-generic
linux-tools-common
localechooser-data
lshw
lvm2
memtest86+
mesa-utils
mesa-utils-bin
mtr-tiny
neochat
netcat-openbsd
netplan-generator
netplan.io
networkd-dispatcher
network-manager-openconnect
network-manager-pptp
numactl
okular-extra-backends
openconnect
openoffice.org-hyphenation
p7zip-full
pastebinit
pcmciautils
phonon4qt5settings
pinentry-qt
pkexec
plasma-calendar-addons
plasma-discover-backend-snap
plasma-discover-notifier
plasma-distro-release-notifier
plasma-theme-oxygen
plasma-workspace-wallpapers
plocate
plymouth-theme-breeze
plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo
plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text
plymouth-theme-spinner
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
policykit-desktop-privileges
powermgmt-base
power-profiles-daemon
ppa-purge
pptp-linux
python3-apport
python3-asn1crypto
python3-bpfcc
python3-commandnotfound
python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5
python3-distro-info
python3-distupgrade
python3-gdbm
python3-launchpadlib
python3-markdown
python3-markdown-it
python3-mdurl
python3-mechanize
python3-mutagen
python3-netaddr
python3-netifaces
python3-netplan
python3-problem-report
python3-pycryptodome
python3-rich
python3-systemd
python3-typing-extensions
python3-update-manager
python3-websockets
python3-xkit
python3-yaml
qapt-batch
qapt-deb-installer
qml-module-org-kde-kaccounts
qml-module-org-kde-kirigami-addons-components
qml-module-org-kde-kirigami-addons-delegates
qml-module-org-kde-kirigami-addons-labs-components
qml-module-org-kde-kquickimageeditor
qml-module-org-kde-notifications
qml-module-org-kde-qqc2breezestyle
qml-module-qtlocation
qml-module-qtpositioning
qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel
qml-module-sso-onlineaccounts
qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts
qtspeech5-flite-plugin
qtvirtualkeyboard-plugin
reiserfsprogs
rfkill
rsyslog
samba-dsdb-modules
sbsigntool
secureboot-db
session-migration
signond
signon-kwallet-extension
signon-plugin-password
signon-ui-service
signon-ui-x11
skanlite
skanpage
snapd
spice-vdagent
squashfs-tools
strace
sysstat
systemd-hwe-hwdb
systemd-resolved
tcpdump
telnet
thermald
thin-provisioning-tools
time
tnftp
trace-cmd
ubuntu-drivers-common
ubuntu-kernel-accessories
ubuntu-keyring
ubuntu-minimal
ubuntu-mono
ubuntu-pro-client
ubuntu-pro-client-l10n
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt
ubuntu-standard
ufw
unattended-upgrades
update-manager-core
update-notifier-common
usb-creator-common
usb-creator-kde
user-setup
uuid-runtime
vim
vim-runtime
vpnc-scripts
vulkan-tools
wayland-utils
wbritish
whoopsie
whoopsie-preferences
wvdial
xfsprogs
xinput
xorriso
xserver-xorg-video-qxl
yt-dlp

What can I do to make it available on Debian Testing? I'd like to avoid installing Brother's drivers, as this was not required on Kubuntu.

Not being required to install the driver in Kubuntu is a pleasant surprise. Up until now I had to install Brother's drivers for a few printers. Maybe something in the Ubuntu specific firmware packages installs support for printers now. If you don't have it in Debian them I'm afraid you'll need to do it the old way.

According to documentation, Brother DCP 9022 DCW is IPP-capable and uses Bonjour/mDNS to announce itself. That means CUPS should be automatically detecting the printer and be able to print to it without explicit configuration, unless incoming packets to port UDP/5353 are blocked.
If you have applied nftables/iptables/firewalld/ufw to your system, make sure that port is unblocked. Incoming SNMP responses might need to be explicitly allowed too (i.e. UDP packets with the source port number 161), to allow CUPS to check the printer status.
For actual printing, outgoing connections to the printer's TCP port 631 (IPP) should do the trick; but usually this is allowed by default.

I tried to disable all mentioned firewalls. I think it was solved by sudo systemctl disable firewalld followed by a reboot. I have the device available now.

If you want to re-enable firewalld, it looks like you can enable mDNS access with firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=mdns; firewall-cmd --reload.
